# Content_tag escapes the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
span_tag = content_tag(:span, class: "123")
```

It generates the following html:

```
<span>{:class=&gt;&quot;123&quot;}</span>
```

I wonder, what's up with this? Shouldn't it be just `<span class="123"></span>` which is exactly what I want? Do I necessarily have to use `.html_safe`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
span_tag = content_tag(:span, nil, class: "123")
```

Answer (score 0):

From doc

> content_tag(name, content_or_options_with_block = nil, options = nil,
>   escape = true, &block)

pass empty block:

```
span_tag = content_tag(:span, class: "123") {}
"<span class=\"123\"></span>"
span_tag = content_tag(:span, class: "123") { 'foo' }
"<span class=\"123\">foo</span>"
```